# Do we need to Peer every Data fusion instance to the Shared VPC ? How to avoid the 25 peering limitation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, google-cloud-networking

**Use Case :** Using GCP Data Fusion as an ETL for customers

**Source and Resources :** My resources are on a shared VPC ( dataproc and runtime for data fusion on subnets taken from this shared VPC )

Based on the documentation of google data fusion, I need to setup VPC peering between the Google managed tenant project VPC and my shared VPC

If i end up spinning multiple Data fusion instances > 25, does that mean that I have to peer every instance to my share VPC ? How do i avoid the 25 peering quota limitation on google cloud ?

Is it possible to have or configure all data fusion instances use the same tenant project ( google managed behind the scenes ) so that I just have to setup 1 VPC peer between the tenant project VPC & my own shared VPC ? The documentation here https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/networking#expandable-1 states that a tenant project can have multiple data fusion instances ? Is that controllable ?

Comment: Hi @Sam- Tahir, you can configure multiple Data Fusion instances to use the same tenant project which you can use to setup 1 VPC peer between the tenant project and the shared VPC , For more information, you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/networking#expandable-1). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar how do you do that ? Based on my testing, you have no control over the google managed tenant project. Each CDF instance gets its own VPC which you need to manually peer. Can you kindly tell me how to control this ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is the best practice. If you absoloutly want multiple Data Fusion instances to run on the same VPC, then just create a specific Dataproc profile to run on this VPC.

You can also create an enterpise edition instance, with RBAC activated and have multiple namespaces. Like so, meach namespace can independantly launch and manage pipelines on different VPCs, whilst only peering the instance to one VPC.